# Very Large Number of Web Calls from Java Code

Tags: java, multithreading, url, volumes

I am writing a program in Java which has to make around 6.5 million calls to various pages on same server (URL will be slightly altered by appending a user name that will be read from a text file) .. Firstly I want to know the most time efficient way of doing this, secondly can anybody give a guess as to how much time this may consume?? Currently I am reading each url in a separate thread of ExecutorService object .. something like this

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(allUsers[n]);
executor.execute(worker);
```

and the run method looks like:

```
is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    page = page + line;

    // More code follows

}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Batch / bulk request?

Comment: *can anybody give a guess*: 5 hours? 6 days? 2 minutes? A guess doesn't mean anything. Measure instead of guessing.

Comment: Ok if anybody has measured handling that amount of calls then please share

Comment: Is this a server you own?  Make sure to be a good citizen and adhere to robots.txt and also be careful not to get blacklisted.  You could also setup a cluster too.

Comment: @MZAmin: you should realize that the performance of my server, using the technology I chose, on my network and hardware, and executing my business logic, has nothing to do with the performance of your server, running your logic on your hardware and network. If your server computes the meaning of life and sends back 5 MBs of data at each request, on a Pentium 2, on a 4kbits/sec network, it will obviously be much slower than computing the sum of 1 and 1, on a gigabit network and a cluster of 8 16-core machines.

Comment: @JBNizet not *that* much faster unless you use a distributed algo to calculate 1+1.

Comment: All that being said, at this scale and over HTTP I guess, you may also want to consider using a dedicated HTTP API which offers connection pooling. That could be a real boost.

Answer (score 0):

- No, nobody can guess how much "time" this will consume. We don't know if the server will take a millisecond or an hour to complete a request.
- The most efficient way is to use a more efficient API, one that allows bulk requests.
- At 10 threads your program will likely be IO bound. You will need to profile the number of threads you need to ensure full CPU use. You can avoid this using Java 7 features / an NIO framework, like Netty or MINA, so one thread can service many requests concurrently. (I'm not sure if these are client side).

Comment: A fixed thread pool, that the OP is using, uses a fixed-size pool of threads to execute many tasks. The OP's code only uses 10 threads, each handling requests sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the other comments and answers that it is impossible to predict how long this will take, and that a "bulk transfer" request will most likely give better performance.

A couple more points:

- If you can use a RESTful API that returns JSON or XML instead of web pages ... that will be faster.
- On the client side, this is going to be efficient if the documents you are fetching are large:

  ```
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          page = page + line;
      }
  ```

  That is going to do an excessive amount of copying.  A better approach is this:

  ```
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(...);
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line);
      }
      page = sb.toString();
  ```

  If you can get a good estimate of the page size, then create the `StringBuilder` that big.